# How to make the text in a web bigger on phone?

Tags: html, css

this is the site

http://www.touziwangzhan.com/en/gpu2.html

i have added viewport, but with image, the text saw on phone is small, how to make the text bigger when see on the phone, what should I add to the code?

this is the site

http://www.touziwangzhan.com/en/gpu2.html

i have added viewport, but with image, the text saw on phone is small, how to make the text bigger when see on the phone, what should I add to the code?

if i higher the initial-scale , sometimes the image will beyond the phone screen

here is the code:

```
     <!doctype html>
        <html>
        
        
        
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="keywords" content="CPU benchmark">
        <meta name="description" conten="CPU benchmark">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.46">
        
        <title>GPU Benchmark, GPU Comparison, GPU Chart - Shenglong</title>
        
        <style>
            a{
            text-decoration:none;}
        #s1{
            max-width: 100%;
            display: block;  }
        #s2{
            font-size:36px;
            text-align:center;
            margin-top:1.2% ;  }
        #s3{
            text-align:right;
            margin-right: 4%;
            margin-top:6.03%;
            font-size:20px;
            color:black;        
            line-height:160%;          }
        </style>

            </head>

            <body>
        
<img id="s1" src="/b1.png" height="90" width="1519" 
style='position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;right:0px;z-index:-1'>
        
<p id="s2" style="color:white">Video Card Photo Chart</p>
        
<div style="text-align:right;margin-right: 0.8%;margin-top:-5.9%;">
<a href="/index.html">1</a></div>
        
<div id="s3" >
<a href="cpu2.html">CPU Benchmark</a>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
<a href="gpu2.html">Video Card Benchmark</a>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
<a href="cpu.html">CPU Photo Chart</a>
&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;<a href="gpu.html">Video Card Photo Chart</a>
</div>
        
<p style="text-align:center"></p><br>
<br><br>
        
<div align="center"><img style="margin-left:0px;margin-top:16px;" src="gpu.jpg">
</div>
        
<div style="text-align:right;">
    <a href="/list2.html" style="color:gainsboro ">n</a></div>
<br><br>
        
<div style="text-align:center">GPU Benchmark, GPU Compare, GPU Comparison, Shenglong</div>
<br>
        
<div style="text-align:center">1014</div>

</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Phones have customs settings, where you can change the text size. But this is a device setting and not done in the code. So every user can decide over there own text size.

Answer (score 1):

You correctly added the [viewport `meta`](//dev.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag) tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.46">
```

To make the content even **larger** set the [`initial-scale`](//dev.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag#viewport_basics) value to `1`.

> The initial-scale property controls the zoom level when the page is first loaded.
> <sub>**MDN Web Docs** | [Using the viewport meta tag to control layout on mobile browsers](//dev.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag#viewport_basics)</sub>

The size of everything should now be readable and similar to larger screens.

Comment: if i higher the initial-scale , sometimes the image will beyond the phone screen, i want to keep the size of image, but make the text bigger

Comment: I tried this on the [site](http://www.touziwangzhan.com/en/gpu2.html) you mentioned and it is working without problems. I'll need to see your code to assist you. Please add it to your question.

Comment: @user16530188 have you solved it or you still need help?

Answer (score 0):

Use media query in CSS to make your text bigger: see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

To check the mobile for example you can use:

```
@media only screen and (pointer: coarse){
   #s3{
      font-size: 30px;
   }
}
```